# Javascript object creation practices

Tags: javascript

This is what I think is best for making an object in js

```
    function obj(){
        var x = "hi";
        this.getX(){return x;}
    }
    var y = new obj()
    console.log(y.x); //this returns undefined
```

But from what I have seen, using this.variable is used more often in object creation.

I am thinking in java where things should be "private" in a class (note I have read about closures), does that apply in js?

What is considered the best way of object creation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Comment: Please show some code to demonstrate what your are asking exactly. From the text of the question, it sounds like a "local variable" is the closer equivalent in Java.

Comment: I was taking that from various posts I read about var vs this. Also I am reading that other link to ee if it helps. Thanks

Comment: @Racialz I now get the concept of closure but, in javascript would I want to program in that manner or would it be better to use "this.variable"

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're trying to apply Java concepts to JavaScript, but things works completely differently in JS. You should check out the [MDN article on JavaScript closures.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

**var** variables exist in the closure. They are accessible from any function declared in the same scope.

```
var me = 'hello';
function someFunction() {
    console.log(me); 
}
someFunction(); //prints 'hello' to console
```

**this** variables will be directly accessible, even outside the scope, in the resulting object.

```
function someFunction() {
    this.me = 'hello';
}
var instance = new someFunction();
console.log(instance.me); //prints 'hello' to console
```

Comment: thanks, that looks more detailed and will look through it. But am I wrong in using it the way I do above? Or no? I'm so confused. It does what I want. thanks

Comment: Without telling us what you want to achieve exactly, there is no "wrong" (or rather, everything that works is "right"). Both patterns have their uses.